# Camera Application by Callling another class

Tags: java, android

I am working on a Flashlight project. I wanna do this by using **another class.**

**Here is my mainactivity.java file:**

```
package com.efsunderin.callcamera;

import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


Button bFlash;
Button cFlash;
MyCamera bnmcamera;
Camera camera;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

bFlash = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFlash);
cFlash = (Button)findViewById(R.id.closeFlash);

bFlash.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        bnmcamera.getCamera();
        bnmcamera.turnOnFlash();

    }
});


cFlash.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        bnmcamera.turnOffFlash();

    }
});

}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    // on stop release the camera
    if (camera != null) {
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

**In this activity I am calling the class below:**

```
package com.efsunderin.callcamera;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;

public class MyCamera {



Camera camera;
Parameters params;


public void getCamera() {


    camera.open();
    params = camera.getParameters();
    camera.startPreview();

}

public void turnOnFlash() {

    params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    camera.setParameters(params);
    camera.startPreview();

}

public void turnOffFlash() {

    params = camera.getParameters();
    params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
    camera.setParameters(params);
    camera.startPreview();

}


}
```

But it's not working, the system shutdown the app when I touch the button to turn on flash. What am I doing wrong? Please help. thanks.

---

Here is **logcat** **output:**

```
    08-31 08:53:22.157: D/AndroidRuntime(287): CheckJNI is ON
08-31 08:53:22.347: D/AndroidRuntime(287): --- registering native functions ---
08-31 08:53:23.247: D/dalvikvm(218): GC_EXPLICIT freed 406 objects / 23512 bytes in 68ms
08-31 08:53:23.367: D/PackageParser(58): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl50609.tmp
08-31 08:53:23.586: I/PackageManager(58): Removing non-system package:com.eeecoder.callcamera
08-31 08:53:23.586: I/ActivityManager(58): Force stopping package com.eeecoder.callcamera uid=10049
08-31 08:53:23.777: D/PackageManager(58): Scanning package com.eeecoder.callcamera
08-31 08:53:23.777: I/PackageManager(58): Package com.eeecoder.callcamera codePath changed from /data/app/com.eeecoder.callcamera-1.apk to /data/app/com.eeecoder.callcamera-2.apk; Retaining data and using new
08-31 08:53:23.787: I/PackageManager(58): /data/app/com.eeecoder.callcamera-2.apk changed; unpacking
08-31 08:53:23.807: D/installd(34): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/com.eeecoder.callcamera-2.apk' ---
08-31 08:53:25.380: D/dalvikvm(294): DexOpt: load 205ms, verify 971ms, opt 42ms
08-31 08:53:25.427: D/installd(34): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/com.eeecoder.callcamera-2.apk' (success) ---
08-31 08:53:25.427: W/PackageManager(58): Code path for pkg : com.eeecoder.callcamera changing from /data/app/com.eeecoder.callcamera-1.apk to /data/app/com.eeecoder.callcamera-2.apk
08-31 08:53:25.427: W/PackageManager(58): Resource path for pkg : com.eeecoder.callcamera changing from /data/app/com.eeecoder.callcamera-1.apk to /data/app/com.eeecoder.callcamera-2.apk
08-31 08:53:25.427: D/PackageManager(58):   Activities: com.eeecoder.callcamera.MainActivity
08-31 08:53:25.447: I/ActivityManager(58): Force stopping package com.eeecoder.callcamera uid=10049
08-31 08:53:25.667: I/installd(34): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.eeecoder.callcamera-2.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.eeecoder.callcamera-2.apk@classes.dex
08-31 08:53:25.667: D/PackageManager(58): New package installed in /data/app/com.eeecoder.callcamera-2.apk
08-31 08:53:25.897: I/ActivityManager(58): Force stopping package com.eeecoder.callcamera uid=10049
08-31 08:53:26.077: D/dalvikvm(58): GC_EXPLICIT freed 12492 objects / 745576 bytes in 179ms
08-31 08:53:26.277: D/dalvikvm(123): GC_EXPLICIT freed 7018 objects / 337856 bytes in 232ms
08-31 08:53:26.857: W/RecognitionManagerService(58): no available voice recognition services found
08-31 08:53:27.067: D/dalvikvm(150): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3878 objects / 211624 bytes in 638ms
08-31 08:53:27.212: D/dalvikvm(58): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5013 objects / 274168 bytes in 119ms
08-31 08:53:27.217: I/installd(34): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@com.eeecoder.callcamera-1.apk@classes.dex
08-31 08:53:27.267: D/AndroidRuntime(287): Shutting down VM
08-31 08:53:27.287: D/dalvikvm(287): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-31 08:53:27.307: I/AndroidRuntime(287): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
08-31 08:53:27.857: D/AndroidRuntime(299): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
08-31 08:53:27.857: D/AndroidRuntime(299): CheckJNI is ON
08-31 08:53:28.127: D/AndroidRuntime(299): --- registering native functions ---
08-31 08:53:29.177: I/ActivityManager(58): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.eeecoder.callcamera/.MainActivity }
08-31 08:53:29.267: D/AndroidRuntime(299): Shutting down VM
08-31 08:53:29.297: D/dalvikvm(299): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
08-31 08:53:29.337: I/ActivityManager(58): Start proc com.eeecoder.callcamera for activity com.eeecoder.callcamera/.MainActivity: pid=306 uid=10049 gids={1006}
08-31 08:53:29.387: I/dalvikvm(299): JNI: AttachCurrentThread (from ???.???)
08-31 08:53:29.387: I/AndroidRuntime(299): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
08-31 08:53:30.257: I/ActivityManager(58): Displayed activity com.eeecoder.callcamera/.MainActivity: 989 ms (total 989 ms)
08-31 08:53:35.357: D/dalvikvm(123): GC_EXPLICIT freed 965 objects / 55776 bytes in 68ms
08-31 08:53:40.367: D/dalvikvm(218): GC_EXPLICIT freed 117 objects / 5144 bytes in 72ms
08-31 08:53:45.377: D/dalvikvm(257): GC_EXPLICIT freed 759 objects / 55000 bytes in 80ms
08-31 08:54:31.157: D/SntpClient(58): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Here is error log output when I touch the button it gives these output and stopped by the system :

**error log:**

```
    08-31 09:55:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(357): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 09:55:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(357): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-31 09:55:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.eeecoder.callcamera.MyCamera.getCamera(MyCamera.java:24)
08-31 09:55:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.eeecoder.callcamera.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
08-31 09:55:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-31 09:55:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
08-31 09:55:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-31 09:55:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-31 09:55:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-31 09:55:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-31 09:55:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 09:55:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-31 09:55:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-31 09:55:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-31 09:55:19.347: E/AndroidRuntime(357):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I initialized required objects, but it still gives **NullPointerException**, why does it give this error? I don't understand. Please take a look at error log output.

Comment: pst your logcat details

Comment: thanks for answers, Siddhesh and Ripal, I tried them bu still not working. I posted the logcat above, please take a look at it.

Comment: by the way I changed the package name to com.eeecoder.callcamera, it is the original, I am using a tutorial to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized your variables bnmCamera and camera.

```
MyCamera bnmcamera;
Camera camera;
```

initialize those variables and then use it.
if you use variables without initializing it will give you `NullPointerException`.

I think you want to do this:(You have not used camera object anywhere)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

bFlash = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFlash);
cFlash = (Button)findViewById(R.id.closeFlash);
//initialize bnmcamera
bnmcamera = new MyCamera();

bFlash.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        bnmcamera.getCamera();
        bnmcamera.turnOnFlash();

    }
});


cFlash.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        bnmcamera.turnOffFlash();

    }
});

}
```

Camera class:

You dont have start camera preview every time. and if you want do do that you have stop preview if it is already started release the camera and then start again.

check this link [Camera Preview Demo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Preview/src/com/commonsware/android/camera/PreviewDemo.java)

**EDIT:**
try this:

```
public void getCamera() {


    camera = camera.open();
    params = camera.getParameters();
    camera.startPreview();

}
public void turnOnFlash() {
    if(camera != null){
     params = camera.getParameters();
     params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
     camera.setParameters(params);
     camera.startPreview();
    }else{
    Log.e("CHECK","Camera null");
    }

}
```

do this check in all functions.

Comment: thanks for answer, I tried it but not working. I posted the logcat at the bottom of the question. Please take a look at it.

Comment: can you try without changing your package name and check what error you get. i think package name is causing problems here as you have not changed it properly according to me

Comment: I did what you said and posted the error log output above. Please take a look.

Comment: have you initialized variable `bnmcamera = new MyCamera()`?

Comment: you have not initialized camera object in MyCamera class. please check edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to create object first before calling the method.

here you go:

```
private MyCamera=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    **MyCamera bnmcamera=new MyCamera();**

bFlash = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFlash);
cFlash = (Button)findViewById(R.id.closeFlash);

bFlash.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        bnmcamera.getCamera();
        bnmcamera.turnOnFlash();

    }
});
```

Comment: @darin: i can't see the E (i.e. Error) Tag line in your logcat. Have you pasted it entirely or part of it???

Comment: I posted it entirely Ripal. Normally I tested it in my phone. This logcat is from emulator in Eclipse.. It does'Nt work both on phone and emulator.

Comment: It seems that in your logcat, only D (i.e. Debug), I (i.e. Info), W (i.e. Warning) appearing. If it throwing exception, den should be E tag. Can you please look into that logcat again. So i can help you out to make it next step. :)

Comment: To track your error, put your code in try catch block and in catch block write "e.printStackTrace()". this will display actual error messages. hope this will help you. :)